# How to extract a substring using a regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of Strings. Every entry looks like: ENSG00001234.2 
I only need the String between "ENSG" and "."

The result should be: 00001234

How can I use a regex for this in R?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be best if you showed what regexs you tried and what were the resulting problems.

Comment: All right, sorry! next time I know that it has to be more efficient. 
But thank you so much for the answers!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Answer (score 1):

Because you wrote that all entries looks the same, you could also use `substr`

```
x <- c("ENSG00001234.2")
substr(x, 5, 12)
# [1] "00001234"
```

Comment: thank you, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("ENSG([0-9]+)\\..*", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "00001234"
```

---

Or using `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "(?<=ENSG)[0-9]+")
#[1] "00001234"
```

NOTE:  This will still give the output if the length of string changes

#### data

```
str1 <- "ENSG00001234.2"
```